# How to control how a div displays regardless of its contents?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that displays html that comes from a database. Unfortunately, the html from the database can potentially screw up the layout of the entire page.

Is an iframe my only full proof option for making sure the outer container appears in its proper place and without affecting other items on the page? Or are there any strategies for making sure an outer div will always appear in its proper place in its proper size regardless of its contents?

Comment: Please edit the question and add your code for the div, page, etc. Without seeing the HTML layout we cannot answer the question.

Comment: @AlexW Thanks, but the whole idea is that I don't know what the inner html is going to be.

Comment: Questions here are expected to have details about what you've tried and what wasn't working. This question is more along the lines of "code this for me".

Comment: I've tried loading html that comes from a database into a div with a width. If you can't imagine what that code looks like then you probably can't help me anyway. I'm not asking for anyone to code anything for me; I'm asking how to better control the layout of a div regardless of its contents. But go ahead and close my question... it's not like you came here to answer it anyway.

Comment: I'm actually quite proficient in CSS and very confident that I could solve your problem with enough details. I'm also not here for the purely sadistic reason that I want to close your question.  I'm trying to ensure that you get high quality answers and that this question will be useful to others in the future.

Comment: Actually it looks like my problem in some cases is that the html from the database is malformed... in which case I imagine the only way to really contain that would be to use an iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the following style to your misbehaving div:

```
div{
  max-width: 500px; // adjust to your liking
  overflow: hidden; // prevents strings from seeping out the div
}
```

You can do the same with max-height, but that's less necessary in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about the text Screwing up the entire page, you could you css property

```
   <style>
    #text-scroll
    {
      text-overflow: scroll;
    }
   </style>
```

```
<div id="text-scroll">
//some content from database
</div>
```